# Prediction of a Future Value of a Random Variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, problem-solving, poisson-distribution

Suppose that $X∼\mathrm{Poisson}(5).$ What value would you record as a prediction of a future value of $X?$ How would you justify your choice?

Comment: $4$ or $5$. Because $P(X=4)=P(X=5)>P(X=k)$ for $k\notin\{4,5\}$

Comment: Welcome. However, please edit your Question to clarify how accurate you want the prediction to be. Also consider the Empirical Rule and comment on answers $\mu\pm\sigma,$ $\mu\pm 2\sigma,$ $\mu\pm 3\sigma.$ // Want to see what you have tried and know why that wasn't adequate.

Answer (score 2):

Predict with *what accuracy*? If you want an approximately
95% prediction set, then maybe $x\in [1,9].$ In R:

```
qpois(c(.025,.975), 5)
[1]  1 10
sum(dpois(1:9, 5))
[1] 0.961434

x = 0:15;  pdf = dpois(x, 5)
plot(x, pdf, type="h", lwd=3, 
     ylab="PDF", main="POIS(5)")
 abline(v = c(.5, 9.5), col="red", lty="dotted")
 abline(h=0, col="green2");  abline(v=0, col="green2")
```

[image]

Simulation:

```
set.seed(2020)
x = rpois(10^6, 5)
mean(x >= 1 & x <=9)
[1] 0.961627
```

*Note:* Although a normal approximation to $\mathsf{Pois}(\lambda=5)$ is not very good, we have $\mu=\sigma^2 = 5,
\sigma = \sqrt{5},$ so $\mu \pm 1.96\sigma$ gives
the same set of integers. [This method works quite reliably for larger $\lambda.$ For example, if $Y\sim \mathsf{Pois}(\lambda = 25),$ then $P(16 \le Y \le 34) \approx 0.94.]$